# does anyone know how to write a list of primes up to n, using a list comprehension?

Tags: python

does anyone know how to write a list of primes up to n, using a list comprehension?
I have this code so far which is efficient, but I want a code just as efficient but in a list comprehension! thanks for the help!

my code:

```
primes = [2]
for i in range(3, n + 1, 2): 
    isprime = True 
    for j in primes:
        if i % j == 0:  
            isprime = False  
            break  
    if isprime: 
        primes.append(i)
```

Comment: http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk

Comment: "I want a code just as efficient but in a list comprehension" Is there a specific reason, or just out of curiosity, that you want that?

Comment: this is coursework for computing so if there is anyway to get a good efficient code on one line I will get a lot of bonus points! if people want to change the code a lot to fit it in one line that will still be great! :)

Comment: You won't deserve any bonus points if you just ask for an answer.

Comment: I'm not sure "good efficient code" and "on one line" are synonyms: some one-liners are pretty incomprehensible. Further, how do you define "efficient"? Least characters, fastest run-speed, easiest maintable?

Comment: A hint for your current code though: use [`for-else`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops), so you can get rid of the `isprime` flag.

Comment: Well basically is there anyway to write my above code on one line, for example, primes = [i for i in range(3, n + 1, 2) if i % j == 0 for j in primes]

Comment: Not this code, since you append to `primes`, which is also your final result. That will not work in a list comprehension. You'll need to find another prime algorithm.

Comment: that is what I thought as well, but didn't know if other people who knew more code could help! thank you for the for-else tip! that has made it look a lot neater!

Comment: Also, why did my post get marked down? what does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that there is any way to use the previously-generated contents of a list while it's still being constructed during a list comprehension.  The first usable reference to that list object appears only at the end of construction as the expression result.

You can use a similar idea, a generator expression, to remove the inner loop, though:

```
if all(i%j != 0 for j in primes):
    primes.append(i)
```

That's efficient in that all accepts an iterable, and stops at the first false result, just as your for loop does.

I haven't timed this to see whether this is faster or not.  It can't be "algorithmically" faster, since it does the very same operations in the same order.  One time should be approximately a fixed fraction of the other for large operations.

The [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) is usually much faster than trial division (your method) for generating all primes from 2 through n.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do it with your algorithm, but you could check if the number n is divisible by a number between n and square root of n (you wanted to check prime numbers only):

```
primes = [i for i in range(2, n+1) if all(i%i2 for i2 in range(2, int(sqrt(i))))]
```

primes is now a list of all primes between 2 and 100.

This is probably less efficient than your approach, but it uses list comprehension and is therefore much less code.

EDIT:
I just figured out the efficiency of my solution with the timeit module and my solution is more than 10 times slower than yours. You shouldn't use it.